# How To Resize Image Automatically Based On window Resolution

Tags: html, css, image, resize

I currently facing issues when i tried to resize my image based on different resolution. The output i try to achieve was like: http://jaxboxtech.com

Below is my code:

```css
#container{
  width: 100%;    
}

#img{

background: transparent center no-repeat url('image.png');      
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
max-height: 850px;
background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<html>
       <body>
          <div>                
             <button>Efficiency</button>               
             <button>Power Metering</button>                                            
        </div> 

           <div id="img">               

             <img src='image.png' alt="" />

        </div>  

      </body>
   </html>
```

Unfortunately it can't auto resize based on browser. Please kindly advise which part of this code i did wrongly. Thank you very much.

Comment: Which image, the one that you have defined in your html or the one you're setting as the background image on your div?  Also, there's a stray `</a>` tag with no matching opening tag.

Comment: @lamelemon that 1 is typo i corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize your image as per your div size then use the image as div background and remove the image tag from your code.(Which is how your example does)

If you don't want to resize the image use the image tag and remove `background` property from you style.

Comment: i want my image as background and i got certain wording over the image

Comment: Hi i have put together a JSfiddle for your reference [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/subhrajyoti21/onby3p5v/). What i have done in adjusted height and width as the screen resolution changes. Hope this helps.